# Permutation representation of a group

Tags: permutations, definition

Consider the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ of a graph $\Gamma$ on the edges of $\Gamma$. My book states that this is not always a permutation group.

**Question 1**: Why is this not always a permutation group?

Now the following definition is given

> Consider a group $G$ and a set $X$. $(G,X)$ is called a permutation representation if
>
> - each element $g \in G$  defines a permutation of $X$ (the image under that permutation of an element $x\in X$ is written as $x^g$) and
> - the operation (mostly composition) in $G$ corresponds with the composition as permutations, i.o.w., if $\forall g,h\in G,x\in X: x^{(gh)}=(x^g)^h$.

**Question 2**: Are the elements in $G$ permutations themselves or are they mapped to a permutation? (This is a very confusing definition, so maybe somebody could help me out with an alternative one, please).

**Question 3**: What is the difference between a permutation group and a permutation representation. They seem to both contain permutations (well, if the answer to question 2 is that $G$ contains permutations).

Thanks.

Comment: How does your book define a permutation group?

Comment: Consider a non-empty set $X$ and a set $G$ of permutations of $X$. Then $(G,X)$ is called a permutation group if (1) $\forall g,h\in G: gh \in G$, (2) $\operatorname{id}_X \in G$ and (3) $\forall g\in G: g^{-1} \in G$.